# Verilog Falling Edge Detection

Tags: synchronization, verilog, clock, hdl

I am writing the Verilog code for a UART to be implemented on a FPGA, and I have some trouble with synchronizing to the START bit of bytes after the first one.

My manager suggested to synchronize my received signal and use some kind of interrupt as a mean of communicating to my FSM that a start has been recognized.

I have read about techniques for rising edge detection, and I feel like I could do something like this:

```
module StartDetectionUnit (
    input clk, state, signal_in,
    output trigger
    );   

    reg signal_d;

    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            signal_d <= signal_in;
        end
    assign trigger = signal_in & (!signal_d);

endmodule
```

In my understanding, a description like this detects a RISING edge, not a FALLING edge, but "START" is a logic '0' in RS-232 communications.

Plus, I want to actually assign the flag just when in IDLE state [Hardcoded as 000] but doing crazy gating on the final assignments sounds non-hardwareish to me.

tldr, two issues

1. detecting a generic falling edge of an asynchronous input signal
2. doing so in a single, specific state of a FSM

thanks a bunch, i'm new to Verilog and kinda-new to HDL'ing

Answer (score 2):

If your signal signal_in come from outside of your design it is not synchronized correctly. In your design you are using only one d-latch, two are required.

```
reg signal_d;
always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        signal_d <= signal_in;
    end
```

This will synthesize only one d-latch. To synchronize signal correctly you have to declare a second signal for two d-latch instantiation:

```
reg signal_d;
reg signal_sync;
always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        signal_d <= signal_in;
        signal_sync <= signal_d;
    end
```

And signal_d should not be used in your design. Then to make edge detection you have to declare a third signal like it :

```
reg signal_d;
reg signal_sync;
reg signal_sync_old;
always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        signal_d <= signal_in;
        signal_sync <= signal_d;
        signal_sync_old <= signal_sync;
    end
```

And for a falling edge detection do :

```
assign trigger = signal_sync_old & (!signal_sync);
```

A good website for more information about synchronization :
https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/synchronisation/

As I understand, your signal 'state' is coded in 3 bits, then you can do :

```
assign trigger = (state == 3'b000) ? (signal_sync_old & (!signal_sync)):0;
```

Comment: to clarify:
"Signal_in" is the bit I am received from my USB-To-UART bridge or testbench during simulation.

    module StartDetectionUnit (
    input clk, state, signal_in,
    output trigger
    );
      
    reg signal_d;
      
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            signal_d <= signal_in;
        end   
 
    assign trigger = (!signal_in) & signal_d & (!state);
    endmodule  


I wrote it like this, and it seems to work correctly by my first few simulation iterations.

The state I need to operate in, is coded as "000".

Comment: Asynchronous external input signal can't be simulated. It will always works in simulation.

Comment: Even through a testbench?

Comment: Sorry if I am sounding clueless, but I have mostly academic experience and my head manager is not exactly strictly following my work on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think the basic falling edge detection fails when your main clock sampling rate is high. It takes time for the incoming baud signal to transit from high to low. Once you detect the high-low transition (in the middle of the falling baud signal), you run the risk of trying to detect it again before it actually hits the ultimate low value. In this case you would have a low to low detection so the falling transition is lost. The way I'm going to tackle this is to have the detector latch as soon as the falling edge is detected so that a manual restart must be done for it to detect a second time.

Answer (score -3):

For synchronous design, the falling edge detection can be done in this way.

```
module StartDetectionUnit (
    input clk, state, signal_in,
    output trigger
    );   

    reg signal_d;

    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            signal_d <= !signal_in;
        end
    assign trigger = !(signal_in | signal_d);
endmodule
```

Here is the state diagram and calculations for the above logic.

[image: Falling Edge Detection - Synchronous]

The falling edge detection can be done in the following way.

```
assign sout = !(sin | (!sin));
```